# Breakpad init - per library?

Tags: google-breakpad

Sorry for newbie question.I have libnative_exception_handler.so with breakpad init:

```
google_breakpad::MinidumpDescriptor descriptor(".");
google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler eh(descriptor, NULL, breakpad_callback, NULL, true, -1);
```

and libfunc.so with unsafe functions.

Both libs are loaded in android using `System.loadLibrary();`

if breakpad init is done in `libnative_exception_handler.so` signals are not catched and breakpad callback is not invoked. if i change `libfunc.so` source to init breakpad signals are catched. So does breakpad need to be init in the same library where unsafe function are?.

Update: I've create lib and demo app to demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/4ntoine/Acra-breakpad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler eh` needs to be init in heap, not in stack.